# react switch in router is rendering all the route elements that matches

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i have a react switch like this and my problem is it will render notfound component with all the other cases at the same time at the end of the page and i cant get rid of the BrowserRouter because it will cause an eror saying Route should be inside a router
 I just want to render the first matching case

```
function App() {
    return (
<BrowserRouter>
    <switch>
        <Route path={"/"} exact  component={Hi}></Route>
        <Route path={"/movies"} exact  component={Layout} />
        <Route path={"/404"} exact component={NotFound}/>
        <Route component={NotFound}></Route>

    </switch>
</BrowserRouter>




    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the exact path like below:

```
    function App() {
     return (
     <BrowserRouter>
      <switch>
         <Route exact path="/"  component={Hi}></Route>
         <Route exact path="/movies"   component={Layout} />
         <Route exact path="/404" component={NotFound}/>
         <Route path="*" component={NotFound}/>
      </switch>
     </BrowserRouter>
);
}
```

Comment: I know i should use exact but i want to render NotFound component when the user types a wrong url that does not match other route elements

Comment: Okay, I have edited my code for the functionality as desired by you. Hope it works now

Comment: unfortunately its not working there is no difference with path={"*"} and writhing no path

Comment: I use this method always for all my projects and it works fine maybe if you can share your code on fiddle then we can find the exact bug